# How can I get only the active calories from Google Fit API?

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am able to get the calories data from Google FIT, but it includes inactive calories too. If by bucket by activity type, I still get activities like sleep and still. I need to calculate only the calories burnt by user by doing any activity (active calories). How is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that you use the Fitness.HISTORY_API. You need to work with Fitness.SESSIONS_API instead. [Sessions](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions) represent a time interval during which users perform a fitness activity.